# Simple Route to an action in another controller

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, routes, annotations

i have an MVC .Net C# project. have Plan Action under Home Controller.
but i dont want to access this page as http://....../Home/Plans
but i want to access it as http://....../Plans
but i dont want to create Plans Controller. so i dont want to do a redirectToAction.

i am trying to use the Route Annonation as the following:

```
[Route("plans/")]
public ActionResult Plans()

[Route("plans/{actions}")]
public ActionResult Plans()

[Route("plans/index")]
public ActionResult Plans()
```

but none of the above worked for me. can you guys help me in this.

**Updated:**

this is my action under HomeController

```
[Route("plans")]
public ActionResult Plans()
{
    var servicePlansDto = SubscriberApiManager.SubscriptionSellingService.GetServicePlans(ServiceId).FindAll(sp => !sp.HasPromotionCode);
    List<ServicePlanVm> servicePlansVm = Mapper.Map<List<ServicePlanDto>, List<ServicePlanVm>>(servicePlansDto);
    return View(servicePlansVm);
}
```

and this is my configurations

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all remember to configure attribute routing:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Then take care that each controller function has to have a different name. In the example they have the same name and this is not accepted by the compiler.

Lat but not least, what's the need of the {actions} parameter in the routing attribute? When you define an attribute routing you don't need to define an action, as you your attribute is already decorating an action / method. You can have required / optional parameters in your routing but they usually correspond to a matching parameter in the method's sugnature:

```
    //Example http://www.domain.com/plans/123
    [Route("plans/{productId}")]
    public ActionResult Plans(string productId)
    {
        ...
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your response, my attribute routings configured as you are mentioning it the first part. i dont have a product ID to pass, my action is just 
plans(){} without any parameters. I have tried [Route("plans/")] but it failed.

Comment: my controller is Home controller, i dont have plans controller.
i want if i type ...../plans it calls me the actions Plans under the Home Controller.

if i typed ..../Home/Plans it will work fine, if i typed /Plans it gives me 404.
as i added the route as the following [Route("/plans")]

Comment: i have added my code to my question, please check it, still it did not worked for me

Comment: i have closed visual studio and run it again, it worked for me.